# Resetting a Wii to factory settings

Tags: nintendo-wii

I am donating my Nintendo Wiis to a group of people far more deserving of them however after turning them on for the first time in ages they're all full of old saves, old miis, network settings, games and game saves.

Is there an easy way to just nuke everything and reset them all completely back to factory settings?

Comment: The accepted answer should be changed to your self-answer. It's much more detailed with screenshot examples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember, the answer is based on [this official guideline](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2757/p/604) by Nintendo. Basically, you go to the third page of settings of your Wii and then select 'Format Wii System Memory'. Then press 'Format' and TA-DA! Warm note: after you reset it all the data will *POOF* gone. You can't restore it.

Answer (score 35):

From the Wii start screen select the Wii button in the bottom left of the screen to open up Wii menu:

[image]

On the Wii menu select Wii Settings to open up System Settings:

[image]

Press the blue arrow [image] on the right twice to get to System Settings 3:

[image]

Select "Format Wii System Memory".